# How to return a Boolean in a completion handler in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures, completionhandler

I'm trying to refactor my code and would like to return a `Bool` inside a `closure`. When I try it says it is unused and doesn't work. I can do it another way but I'm repeating code that I don't want to do. How can I go about it.

```
func tableView(_ pTableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt pIndexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

    // These lines are the one that work but would like to get rid of them
    if let rowConversation = self.objectAtIndexPath(pIndexPath) as? Conversation {
        if rowConversation.isGroupChat && rowConversation.expired  {
            return true
        }
    }

    self.getRowConversation(pIndexPath: pIndexPath) {
        // how to return true here
    }
    return false
}

private func getRowConversation(pIndexPath: IndexPath, completion pCompletion: () -> Void) {
    if let rowConversation = self.objectAtIndexPath(pIndexPath) as? Conversation {
        if rowConversation.isGroupChat && rowConversation.expired  {
            ConversationManager.shared.deleteConversationID(rowConversation.conversationID)
            pCompletion()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't run the `getRowConversation` in an asynchronous way, so there is no need for the `pCompletion` in that function. Simply let it return true/false instead. If your question is "how can I run `getRowConversation` asynchronously and still return true/false from the `tableView()`", then the answer is: you cannot. In order to use the result value, you need to wait for the function to finish.

Comment: What is `objectAtIndexPath` which returns an optional? Are there other types as `Conversation`? The code looks pretty cumbersome.

Answer (score 7):

You are probably over-thinking this. No "closure" is needed here; no "completion handler" is needed. Nothing asynchronous is happening. Just turn `getRowConversation` into an ordinary function that returns a Bool; call it and return the result that it passes back to you.

```
private func getRowConversation(pIndexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if let rowConversation = self.objectAtIndexPath(pIndexPath) as? Conversation {
        if rowConversation.isGroupChat && rowConversation.expired  {
            ConversationManager.shared.deleteConversationID(rowConversation.conversationID)
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

And call it like this:

```
func tableView(_ pTableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt pIndexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return self.getRowConversation(pIndexPath: pIndexPath)
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? It compiles and it satisfies the question's requirements based on the information given. If there is more relevant code to show, then show it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you want to return a result that is produced asynchronously in `getRowConversation(pIndexPath: pIndexPath)` before it is delivered, i.e. immediately after this function is called in `tableView(_ pTableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt pIndexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool`.
This is simply not possible, since the result is not yet known at this time.
You had to change (if this is possible) your function `tableView(_ pTableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt pIndexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool` so that is also has a callback, e.g.
`tableView(_ pTableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt pIndexPath: IndexPath, completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void))`, and to use the result only in the completion block.